# Loging with SSH with a different user, shows no current path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, path, directory

I am trying to get a server up and running, there is no problem when I am using my root user, however when I created a new user and I log in with him instead of getting 
user@internet:/$

I am only geting $ and I can't see the folder in which I am.

The server is running ubuntu if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new user is probably using a different shell. You can check by typing $0 at the prompt in each.

It sounds like root is using bash and your new user is using sh, but do the above to check.

If you want to modify the login shell for your new user, use usermod with the -s flag:

```
usermod user -s /bin/bash
```

The above would set the default shell to bash.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your user runs `sh` as default shell.

Run as root:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash your_user
```

And login again.